# How do I get the model for the selected <option> in a Marionette.js CollectionView?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Marionette CollectionView that renders an ItemView into a `<select>` menu, with each ItemView rendering as an `<option>`. My question is, when I call the 'change' event on the CollectionView (meaning the user has selected an option), how do I get the model of the selected `<option>` from the ItemView?

```
var singleView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: '#optionTemplate',
        tagName: 'option'
    });

var listView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        itemView: singleView,
        tagName: 'select',
        id: 'my-selector',
        events: {
            'change': 'optionSelected'
        },
        optionSelected: function() {
          // I need to get the model from within this function

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleanest approach is to render the `option` tag with the ID of the corresponding model as the value: `<option value="42">Forty Two</option>`. Then, on change, get that value and use it to retrieve the model from the collection by ID with `collection.get(id)`. Some elements like `option` have a natural attribute that makes sense to be the model ID, but for other elements you can just use a `data-id="42"` attribute.

Another approach that is viable although I think less simple and clean than the above would be to use jQuery's `.data` method or equivalent to associate the model instance with the element.

Comment: That's funny, I actually just came up w/that solution. Thanks for confirming it though!

Comment: I'm dealing with this issue at the moment... You'd think Marionette would give you access to the view that triggered the change and subsequently, the view's model.

Comment: "> Then, on change, get that value and..." -- How to exactly get that value?

Comment: How do you propose to add this value to the option tag? The view creates the option tag, but it is the template that receives the information about the model (including the ID).

Comment: You would just use you template language's basic interpolation feature to inject data into the output HTML from the template's render data set, which includes the model something like: `<option value="#{model.id}">#{model.get("name")}</option>`.

Answer (score 2):

No need to add custom IDs and such, and also danmactough's answer doesn't work so best ignore it. Even `childEvents` in Marionette won't work with select/option tags.

My method would be to just bind to the `change` event on the `CollectionView` and match the index of model within the collection and the `:selected` element within the dropdown:

```
var listView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: singleView,
    tagName: 'select',
    id: 'my-selector',
    events: {
        'change': 'optionSelected'
    },
    optionSelected: function() {
      // The selected model:
      var model = this.collection.at($(':selected', this.$el).index()));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better, Marionette-specific solution would be to use the `modelEvents` or `collectionEvents` configuration hash [available in a CollectionView or CompositeView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewmodelevents-and-viewcollectionevents).

```js
var listView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: singleView,
    tagName: 'select',
    id: 'my-selector',
    modelEvents: {
        'change': 'modelChanged'
    },
    modelChanged: function(e) {
      // "e" is the event
      // "this" is the ItemView
      // "this.model" is the model  
    }
});
```

Comment: How does the item view (the option tag) modify its model on the select menu's change event?